# Question Related to Theorem that "Union of Two Measurable Sets is Measurable"

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu^* :  \mathcal{P}(X) \rightarrow [0, \infty]$ be an outer measure, and let $M$ denote the set of $\mu^*$-measurable sets.

Let $A \subseteq X$ and let $E,F \in M$.

Why is the following statement true?

$\mu^*(A \cap E^c) = \mu^*(A \cap F \cap E^c) + \mu^*(A \cap E^c \cap F^c)$

EDIT: Is it because $F \in M$, with $(A \cap E^c)$ serving as our "test set"?

Comment: Yes (and in this case, it would be better to write $\mu^*(A\cap E^c\cap F)$ in order make make this clearer)

Comment: $A \cap E^c = (A \cap F \cap E^c) \cup (A \cap E^c \cap F^c)$. Is your question about this statement or about the theorem in the title?

Comment: What I wrote is required to understand the proof of the theorem I wrote in the title.  I understand everything now -- thanks for the help.

Comment: You can answer your own question :-) (to remove this from the list of unanswered questions).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a special case of the property defining measurable sets, applied to $F$ against $A\cap E^c$.